# How to get last and next date from a date number in php?

Tags: php

I want to find entries in a month range based on date of a month

like if a user registered on 20th of a month, the script should get entries in a range from last 20th to next 20th of the month.

I.e if the script is running on any day before 20th of April the range should be March 20 - April 20, and if its running on 20th April or after then the range should be April 20 - May 20.

I looked up relative formats but it only lists functions for day names and weeks etc.

Is there any way the relative date format works like last n to next n. where n= 1 to 31.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Based on comment from Cully, here is an implementation (it still feels too messy, maybe there is an easier way to do it). It may explain the question a bit more.

```
function getFromDate($myDate, $nDate)
{
    // sub 1 day till date is $nDate
    while(true)
    {
        if($myDate->format('d')==$nDate)
            break;
        $myDate->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    return $myDate;
}

function getToDate($myDate, $nDate)
{
    // add 1 day till date is $nDate
    while(true)
    {
        $myDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        if($myDate->format('d')==$nDate)
            break;
    }
    return $myDate;
}

$timestamp = 1602107066; // An example user registration date, 7 October 2021
$nDate = gmdate("d", $timestamp);

$fromDate = getFromDate(new DateTime('now'), $nDate);
$toDate = getToDate(new DateTime('now'), $nDate);

echo $fromDate->format('d M y')."\r\n"; // 7 May 2021 (run on May 22 2021)
echo $toDate->format('d M y'); // 7 June 2021 (run on May 22 2021)
```

Comment: Just create a DateTime object for March 20th and use [DateTime::add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) to add 1 day at a time until you get to April 20th (or whatever day you want). E.g. `$nextDay = $currentDate.add(new DateInterval('P1D'))`

Comment: That wont work, it needs to work regardless of the start, user can register on 20th January, and the script can be run on november and it should output a range of november 20 - december 20. I need something like Last 20 - Next 20 or Last 15 to Next 15 etc.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what date range you actually want. But either way, you can use [DateTime::add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) or [DateTime::sub](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) to get any set of dates you want. Start where you want, add 1 day at a time until you get to the end you want. Or start at some date and subtract  1 day a certain number of times until you get the end you want, etc.

Comment: Also, you  might want to update your question and clarify exactly what date range you're asking for. It kinda sounds like you want the 20 days before or after a certain date, but then your example makes it sound like you want the same day (e.g. the 20th), but in the previous or next month. Maybe add more examples.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by date range?  Are you wanting an array of dates incremented by day, hour, seconds? Are you wanting it from 20th to 20th or just 20 days, etc.  It would be helpful if you provided an example of the final results. I think you may be looking for [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php). eg: `$dateRange = new DatePeriod(new DateTime('2020-01-20'), new DateInterval('P1D'), 20);` Which will create an `Iterable` containing 20 dates incremented by 1 day from the date supplied.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't make sense. You're only returning the end date. And you're looping until "day" value of the next/prev month is equal to 'nDate', but that means you know the value that your function returns without actually needing to call it (it's just the next/prev month with the same day value). So why do you need to loop?

Comment: Because it could be running on any day of the month, if nDate is equal to 5th of a month, and it is running on 6th of the month then start date will be 5th of the current month and end date will be 5th of the next month
And if it's running on 4th of the month start date will be 5th of previous month and end date will be 5th of the current month.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? It might not be exactly what you want, but can you use it to create what you want?

```php
<?php

$numberOfDaysIWant = 20;
// March 20th, 2021, but you can use any date you want
$startDate = new DateTimeImmutable('2021-03-20');
$myPastDates = [];
$myFutureDates = [];

$currentDate = $startDate;
for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfDaysIWant; $i++) {
  $currentDate = $currentDate->sub('P1D');
  $myPastDates []= $currentDate;
}

$currentDate = $startDate;
for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfDaysIWant; $i++) {
  $currentDate = $currentDate->add('P1D');
  $myFutureDates []= $currentDate;
}

var_dump($myPastDates, $myFutureDates);
```

It's unclear from your question, but it sounds like maybe you want to get the `$numberOfDaysIWant` value based on the date of the selected month. If so, you could use this to get it:

```php
<?php

$startDate = new DateTimeImmutable('2021-03-20');
$numberOfDaysIWant = (int) $startDate->format('j'); // "j" gives you the day of the month, without leading zeroes
```